# SQL Server Index Design

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table that holds a history of events that have occurred over time, such as:

```
EventType | OccurredOn       | Other.. | Data..
--------------------------------------------
1         | 2014/10/02 09:00 | foo     | bar
1         | 2014/10/02 10:00 | foo     | bar
2         | 2014/10/03 09:00 | foo     | bar
1         | 2014/10/04 09:00 | foo     | bar
3         | 2014/10/05 09:00 | foo     | bar
2         | 2014/10/05 09:00 | foo     | bar
4         | 2014/10/05 09:00 | foo     | bar
```

All my queries on this table will be of the form:

```
select [OccurredOn], [OtherData]
from [Data]
where [EventType] = @type and [OccurredOn] between @start and @end
```

perhaps, with `grouping` and selecting of aggregate data.

Rows will be inserted almost always in time order, when they are inserted out of time order, the `OccurredOn` should be reasonably "recent" - i.e. not too far before the "latest" row already inserted

How should I index this table for efficient selecting?

Presumably my PK should be clustered, and include `OccurredOn` it, however there is no natural unique key, so presumably I need an `autoincrement int` column too?

**Update**

In terms of rows, the table will have millions, possibly 10s of millions

I'm using SQL Server 208R2

Comment: First, [don't use `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First thing - OccurredOn time can have duplicate values.

Start with the following and analyse the execution plan to tweak it later.

I would recommend to add a proxy/surrogate key which is an auto increcement identity column - let's name it as "NewColumn". Keep this "NewColumn" as `Primary Key`. Keep the Primary Key as `Non-Clustered`.

Make a `Unique Clustered Index` with the columns (OccurredOn,NewColumn). This clustered index helps in date range search.

Keeping the "OccurredOn" on Clustered index helps to keep the ever increasing order of Clustered Index.

Keeping the NewColumn along with OccurredOn, helps to make Clustered Index unique. This helps to avoid SQL Server adding a uniquifier by itself (in case of non-unique clustered index)

**REFERENCES**

1. [Is it needed to add additional column to make this clustered index unique?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149612/is-it-needed-to-add-additional-column-to-make-this-clustered-index-unique)
2. [Clustered index on random order column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149225/clustered-index-on-random-order-column)